# WPForo plugin. The login is now wp-adminlogin and I get diferent menues depending on what computer i use?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I use WPForo and all was fine then now al of a sudden the login is to the WordPress-admin page and not to the forum and My restriction is not functioning the forum is visible to anyone and its supposed to be locked and payment, paidmemberpro plugin does not show at all. Can some one help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should go to Dashboard > Forums > Settings > Features admin page and enabled these three options:

- Replace Registration Page URL to Forum Registration Page URL Replace
- Login Page URL to Forum Login Page URL Replace Reset Password Page
- URL to Forum Reset Password Page URL